# Activar modal después de submit

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Intento abrir un modal después de un submit, pero el submit se encuentra en un tab-content, y esto me lleva al tab-content por defecto.

Me gustaría que cuando me llevara al tab-content por defecto me mostrara los datos que acabo de introducir en el form anterior. Mostrar los datos no es un problema, mi problema es que se ejecute el modal justo después del submit en el tab-content por defecto

Gracias.

```js
// Esto me lo carga siempre al principio
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

```html
<div class="col">
   
    <nav>
      <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
  <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-preguntas-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-preguntas" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-preguntas" aria-selected="true">Preguntas frecuentes</a>
  <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-denuncia-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-denuncia" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-denuncia" aria-selected="false">Presente una denuncia</a>
      </div>
    </nav>
 
 <!-- tab-content -->
    <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-preguntas">
            <div>
    <h1>TEXTO</h1>
            </div>
  </div>     
  
  <!-- modal a mostrar -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Modal</h4>
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>HOLA</H1>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
          
    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-denuncia">
        <form>
        <!-- formulario de alta -->
  <!-- este es el submit que quiero emplear -->
   <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit" >Enviar</button>
        </form>
    </div>
 
</div>
```

Comment: agrega algo de codigo. No somos adivinos para saber como estas programando.

Comment: Échale un vistazo a esta respuesta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362470/load-modal-after-form-submit

Comment: Por lo que se ve, el tab por defecto es el nav-preguntas. ¿Tú quieres que habiendo cambiado al nav-denuncias, hacer submit y que te devuelva al nav-preguntas y abra el modal?

Comment: Hola @Sr.J. Es muy importante cómo etiquetas tu pregunta. No tiene nada que ver con PHP, y no sé por qué la etiquetaste así, y en cambio sí tiene que ver con bootstrap. De las etiquetas que uses, dependerá quién lea tu pregunta y qué tipo de respuestas obtengas... Además, podrías [edit] agregando cómo estás incluyendo a jQuery y bootstrap al inicio de tu HTML?

Answer (score 1):

Primero, yo te aconsejaría que si el modal no está pensado para una acción de un tab específico, sácalo del bloque de los navtabs por una cuestión de orden.

Segundo, un elemento de tipo submit siempre envía el formulario y todos los eventos posteriores ya no se ejecutan... a menos que prevengas el comportamiento por defecto. En tu caso:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submit').on('click', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#myModal').modal('show');
    });
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="col">
  <nav>
    <div class="nav nav-tabs" id="nav-tab" role="tablist">
      <a class="nav-item nav-link active" id="nav-preguntas-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-preguntas" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-preguntas" aria-selected="true">Preguntas frecuentes</a>
      <a class="nav-item nav-link" id="nav-denuncia-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#nav-denuncia" role="tab" aria-controls="nav-denuncia" aria-selected="false">Presente una denuncia</a>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- tab-content -->
  <div class="tab-content" id="nav-tabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="nav-preguntas">
      <div>
        <h3>Soy el tab preguntas</h3>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="nav-denuncia">
      <h3>Soy el tab denuncia</h3>
      <form>
        <!-- formulario de alta -->
        <!-- este es el submit que quiero emplear -->
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary btn-block" type="submit">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- modal a mostrar -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="memberModalLabel">Modal</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <b>Soy el modal</b>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Previniendo el comportamiento habitual del submit puedes controlar lo que pasa al presionar ese elemento. Por ejemplo, mostrar el contenido del form en el modal y enviarlo por ajax ya sea de inmediato o previa confirmación.